# C++ persistence in database

Tags: c++, mongodb, postgresql, serialization, boost

I would like to persist some of my objects in a database (this could be relational (postgresql or MariaDB) or MongoDB). I have found a number of libraries that seem potentially useful, but I am missing the overall picture.

I have used boost::serialization serialize c++ to xml / binary, but it is not clear to me how to get this into the database (do I use the binary or xml format?)?

How do I get this into my mongoDB or postgresql?

Comment: This is looking for tool recommendations. Also, quite definitely tag spam.

Comment: Voted to reopen, I can answer this

Comment: Everybody stand back; sehe can answer this

Comment: Cue boost::spirit parsing into a VARCHAR field.

Comment: @DeadMG wrong :) Guess again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd serialize to binary, as it is smaller and much faster. Also, the XML format isn't really pretty/easy to use outside of Boost Serialization anyways.

**WARNING**: Use Boost Portable Archive (EPA http://epa.codeplex.com/) if you need to use the format across different machines.

You'd usually store it in a column

- text or CLOB (character large object) by encoding in base64 and putting that in the Database native charset (base64 is safe even for ASCII)
- BLOB (binary large object) which doesn't bring the need to encode and could be more efficient storage wise.

Note: if you need to index, store the index properties in *normal* database columns.

Finally, if you like, I have recently made a streambuffer that allows you to stream data directly into a Sqlite BLOB column. Perhaps you can glean some ideas from this you could use:

- ***[How to boost::serialize into a sqlite::blob?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20409877/how-to-boostserialize-into-a-sqliteblob/20414105#20414105)***

Comment: thanks! in particular for the portable archive warning.