# writing boost::archive to C# stream

Tags: c#, c++, boost, c++-cli, archive

I was wondering if anyone has any insight on this one.

I have a native C++ object (in a DLL) that writes it's data using boost::archive.

That project is used by a C# application (through a C++/CLI class), and I would like to store several of these archive in a zipped file. I am using Ionic.Zipfile in C# (DotNetZipFile).

Currently, I am writing to a temporary file, then using ZipFile.UpdateFile to add to the archive, but would like to avoid the middle man.

So, here is what I'd like to so:

C#:

```
ZipEntry ae = archive.UpdateEntry("Project", (f, stream) =>
{
   pManagedObjectWrapper.Save(stream);
});
```

C++/CLI:

```
void ManagedObjectWrapper::Save(System::IO::Stream ^ stream)
{
    std::ofstream *myofstream = MAGICALFunction(stream);
    pUnmanagedObject->Save(myofstream);
}
```

C++:

```
void UnmanagedObject::Save(std::ofstream *myofstream)
{
    boost::archive::binary_oarchive oa(*myofstream);
    oa << *this;
}
```

Any assistance for what `MAGICALFunction` is?

Comment: You could/would need to subclass `streambuf` or `ostream` with a class that act as an [adapter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern#Class_Adapter_pattern) to the `System.IO.Stream`, and then pass it to the `UnmanagedObject::Save()`. Not something for the faint of heart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed subclassing a streambuf with proper underflow/overflow implementations is the way to go.

I don't recall this to be very hard, but I also don't have a suitable windows machine available to do it right now, so you'd look around for readymade implementations.

Resources:

- In my experience it wasn't hard to find good working, small samples on SO proper:

  - [How to boost::serialize into a sqlite::blob?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20409877/how-to-boostserialize-into-a-sqliteblob/20414105#20414105); as I remember I used one of [Dietmar Kühl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1120273/dietmar-k%C3%BChl)s answers here (something about an encrypting or compressing stream?)
- Mr Ed has **[an excellent blog](http://www.mr-edd.co.uk/blog/beginners_guide_streambuf)** article¹ that shows you everything that you actually need to get started with just the standard library. It uses 3 different examples to drive the point home.
- Don't forget about Boost IOStreams. As Mr Ed puts it:

  > If you were new to stream buffers before you read this post, I hope you feel a little more comfortable with them now. All the implementations were pretty basic, but a lot more is possible. However, I've found that once I start attempting more extravagant buffers, things can get fiddly pretty quickly. This is when I'll reach for the Boost IOStreams library, which provides a framework for implementing more involved buffers and streams.
  >
  > It also allows you to treat the sources, sinks, filters and other concepts independently of one another. In our final example, we hard coded the sink as another std::ostream. What if we wanted the data to go somewhere that doesn't have a stream interface? The Boost IOStreams library allows more flexibility in this area by isolating concepts that I've had to mash together in my example code.
- cppreference has [the best ever visual explanation of stream buffers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_streambuf):

  [image]

¹ http://www.mr-edd.co.uk/blog/beginners_guide_streambuf

Comment: Honestly, I haven't tried this, because I don't have that much time to work on it right now. I was really hoping for an easy answer, which for now will have to be to keep things as they were. However, this was the best answer (so far as I know), so I marked it as such.